# Raspberry Pi Headless Bluetooth Audio Sink

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B running Rasbian Buster.  I'm writing Jukebox software in Python and want an option to suspend Jukebox operation and enable a bluetooth audio sink.  Press the button again and it disables Bluetooth discovery and reenables the normal processing of the Jukebox software.  Once the raspberry is installed in the physical Jukebox it will be running headless (still going to use the Rasbian O/S with GUI, but not hook up a monitor/etc).

My issue is I can't get the paring to be automatic.  I believe my issue is with Blueman, but not sure how to resolve it.  When I pair my iPhone (or any untrusted device) I get a dialog box on the Raspberry Pi that states:

Pairing Requested
Device 'iPhone' has requested pairing.  Do you accept the request?
Cancel     OK

Obviously, I have to click OK for the connection to go through.  This is fine for my prototype, but need to figure out how to get past this dialog (do I uninstall Blueman, is there an option I'm not finding, etc.).

Using these sites as a guide, here is what I've done so far:

```
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=247892
https://sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/bluetooth_n_buster_01_en.html
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235519
```

1. sudo apt install bluealsa
2. sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluealsa.service
3. edit the ExecStart line and add "--profile=a2dp-sink" to the end of the line
4. once changes have been made, hit Ctrl-X to save and exit
5. sudo adduser pi bluetooth
6. sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/aplay.service

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=BlueALSA aplay service
    After=bluetooth.service
    Requires=bluetooth.service

    [Service]
    User=pi 
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/bluealsa-aplay 00:00:00:00:00:00
    Restart=on-failure  
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=30

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
7. sudo systemctl enable aplay
8. sudo nano /etc/rc.local
9. Add the following lines:

   /bin/hciconfig hci0 piscan &

   /bin/hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1 &
10. sudo apt-get install bluez-tools
11. sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/bt-agent.service

    [Unit]
    Description=Bluetooth Auth Agent
    After=bluetooth.service
    PartOf=bluetooth.service

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/bt-agent -c NoInputNoOutput
    ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 1
    ExecStartPost=/bin/hciconfig hci0 piscan
    ExecStartPost=/bin/hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1

    [Install]
    WantedBy=bluetooth.target
12. sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
13. Uncomment/write out:

```
Class = 0x41C
DiscoverableTimeout = 0
```

14. sudo nano /etc/machine-info

    PRETTY_HOSTNAME=Jukebox
15. Reboot

How do I get past this last dialog box?  Also, is there a service that I can start/stop when I need Bluetooth to be discoverable?

Thanks.  Brian

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on using Bluetooth Audio with the Raspberry Pi at:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/how-to-play-sound-and-make-noise-with-your-raspberry-pi/

which that links to a good guide at:

- https://gist.github.com/actuino/9548329d1bba6663a63886067af5e4cb

However, neither of them cover your two questions of how to turn discovery on/off, and how to pair without needing the screen.

Firstly, you have used `hciconfig` in a couple of places. That command has been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) back in 2017. You should look to use `bluetoothctl` instead. However the following should remove the need for those setup steps.

From Python, the best way would be to use the BlueZ D-Bus API to answer your two questions. There is a [Discoverable](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n268) property on the Adapter interface that will turn it on/off.
There is also an [Agent API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt) that would allow you to accept connections without needing to manually press buttons.

There are examples of how to use these API's at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test